# BizUnit 4.0 - deleting rows from a table

Tags: biztalk

I am upgrading to BizUnit 4.0 and porting the setup step DatabaseDeleteStep.  Apparently in 4.0 there is no db delete step. So I used the DbQueryStep with RawSqlString.  The problem is that its failing with this reason

```
BizUnit.TestStepExecutionException: BizUnit encountered an error executing a test step ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.
```

which is obvious because the raw sql

```
DELETE FROM [AnnuitiesDB].[Staging].[CommonwealthAgents]
```

will not return any tables.

Is there a step equivalent to DatabaseDeleteStep in BizUnit 4.0?

My Code:

```
        var cleanDB = new DbQueryStep();

        cleanDB.ConnectionString =
            "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AnnuitiesDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

        cleanDB.NumberOfRowsExpected = 0;
        cleanDB.SQLQuery = new SqlQuery { RawSqlQuery = "DELETE FROM [Staging].[CommonwealthAgents] where (CwAAgentId='1ead5c1ab65b677f013338baa2e6636fb1c59581' or CwAAgentId='965500bfdb81b2f4595e50cac3078871c5fc4126')" };
        testCase.SetupSteps.Add(cleanDB);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could supplement the raw SQL so that something is returned.

```
DELETE FROM [AnnuitiesDB].[Staging].[CommonwealthAgents];
SELECT 1;
```